# Nearline - Backup Solution - Versioning

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I've setup some Nearline buckets and enabled versioning and object lifecycle management. The use-case is to replace my current backup solution, Crashplan.

Using gsutil I can see the different versions of a file using a command like `gsutil ls -al gs://backup/test.txt`.

First, is there any way of finding files that don't have a live version (e.g. deleted) but still have a version attached?

Second, is there any easier way of managing versions? For instance if I delete a file from my PC, it will no longer have a live version in my bucket but will still have the older versions associated. Say, if I didn't know the file name would I just have to do a recursive `ls` on the entire bucket and sift through the output?

Would love a UI that supported versioning.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. To check if the object currently has no life version use [`x-goog-if-generation-match`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#xgoogifgenerationmatch) header equal to `0`, for example :

   gsutil -h x-goog-if-generation-match:0 cp file.txt gs://bucket/file.txt

will fail (`PreconditionException: 412 Precondition Failed`) if file has a live version and will succeed if it has only archived versions.

2. In order to automatically synchronize your local folder and folder in the bucket (or the other way around) use [`gcloud rsync`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync):

   gcloud rsync -r -d ./test gs://bucket/test/

   - notice the trailing `/` in `gs://bucket/test/`, without it you will receive

> CommandException: arg (gs://graham-dest/test) does not name a directory, bucket, or bucket subdir.

- `-r` synchronize all the directories in `./test` recursively to gs://bucket/test/`
- `-d` will delete all files from gs://bucket/test/`that are not found in`./test`

Regarding UI, there already exists a [future request](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/65302202). I don't know anything about third party applications however.